# How can I do the numbering with fetched records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

This code fetches 10 latest records

```
@comments = @topic.comment_threads.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I'd like to do the numbering to the fetched records.
As it is desc order, it will be something like this

```
"Displaying comments 1 - 10 of 18 in total 

No. 18 Hi
No. 17 Hello
No. 16 Hola
No. 15 Howdy
No. 14 What's up
No. 13 Hi there
No. 12 Yo
No. 11 Oh
No. 10 Ah
No.  9 Eeeee
```

How can I get this No. in the view?
It should be something like

```
<%= "No. " + ????????????? %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE-2:**

for **descending**

```
<% params[:page] = params[:page].blank? ? 1 : params[:page]%>
<% total = @comments.total_count - ((params[:page].to_i-1)*10)+1 %>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= "No. #{total-=1} #{comment}" %>
<% end %>
```

for **ascending**

```
<% params[:page] = params[:page].blank? ? 1 : params[:page]%>
<% i = ((params[:page].to_i-1)*10)+1 %>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= "No. #{i+=1} #{comment}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is it does just No. 1, No. 2, No. 3...... Not like the example in my question

Comment: are you using kaminari for pagination?

Comment: Thanks I got this error undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Comment: check if you are getting 18(total records) for @comments.total_count and params[:page] as current page?

Comment: for which line you are getting the error? I have updated the answer.

Comment: It worked!! I had to add `@` because I was using partial. Thanks!

Comment: you ascending gives wrong number. like -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1

Comment: It's probably because params[:page] in the first page is empty:(

Answer (score 3):

Use **`each_with_index`**

```
@comments.each_with_index.map {|comment, index| "No #{index} #{comment}"}
```

Comment: Thanks! How is it gonna be in view then?